# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}$

(a) converges to $1$

(b) converges to a number $>1$

(c) diverges to $\infty$

(d) has an oscillating sequence of partial sum

How to deal with convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}$.
Here, I can use limit comparision test taking series  $b_{n}=\sum\frac{1}{n^{3}}$ and got $\lim\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=2$, so by limit comparison test, since the series $\frac{1}{n^{3}}$ is convergent, $a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}$ is also convergent.
But will it converge to $1$ or to a number greater than $1$? How should I proceed?

Comment: If you think it might be (a), then something worth checking is whether it is a telescoping series. Often if a rational series (i.e. the terms are quotients of polynomials of $n$) converges to something rational (i.e. a quotient of integers), there's some telescoping hiding in the background. A good way of seeing this is performing a partial fractions decomposition on $\frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2}$. If you think it might be (b), I would start adding terms from the series. If you can find a partial sum that is greater than $1$, then since the terms are positive, you know the series will only increase.

Comment: Another hint: Write out the first few values in the partial series, in reduced fraction form. For this series, a nice simple pattern emerges...

Comment: You already have some good answers on here, but I just wanted to say that $b_n$ is supposed to be the sequence you're taking the series of, so saying $b_n = \sum \frac{1}{n^3}$ makes no sense if you're trying to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Same with what you let $a_n$ equal.

Answer (score 4):

The most important aspect of this problem is to notice that $2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$. From there, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}.$$
Also, note that $\frac{a-b}{ab}=\frac1b-\frac1a$. Then,
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2(n+1)^2} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\\
&=1-\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{3^2}+\dots\end{align*}
I'm sure you can get the final answer from here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use computer or maually calculation, you can find the limit close to 1. So you need to find the limit = 1 instead of use inequality to show it >1.
Then you should notice that the expression looks like a partial fraction type question.

$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}=...$

You can try to finish the rest and show the limit is 1.

If you have problem. I can finish the rest steps later.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} \right),
\end{align}
this sum is telescoping, then taking $N\to+\infty$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} \right)=1.
\end{align}
More reference and examples, see here:

- https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Series_Special.aspx